# Avoid deadlock between `Control.Invoke` and destructor, revisited for a UserControl

Tags: .net, winforms, deadlock, invoke, dispose

I ran into a variation of the problem I asked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520663/windows-forms-is-there-a-way-to-wait-for-all-pending-invokes-to-a-control-to-en). Instead of a class extending `System.Windows.Form`, I have a class extending `System.Windows.UserControl`, which doesn't have the `FormClosing` event.

I thought about adding a `Close` method to the user control, in which I tell the native thread to stop. When it stops, it raises an event to the user control, which calls `Dispose` on itself. The problem with this approach is that calling `Dispose` from the object to dispose (suicide?) seems a bad practice, and I had to write a finalizer that does nothing (to avoid double disposal), which feels even worse...

Suggestions?

**Update:** My user control lives inside a class which extends `System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripControlHost`, and an instance of that class lives in the main application form.

Comment: Is the lifetime of the user control managed by its host? Is the host a windows form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add some sort of method to the user control and call it in the forms `FormClosing` event...

The method in the user control would be blocking so that it didn't return until the disposal was complete.

But, you could cancel the closing in the Closing event, disable the form, do something in the background and when done, close the form from code.  For example:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // if disposed, close as usual
    if (myControl == null || myControl.Disposed) return;
    // disable the form so nothing can be done while
    // were asynchronously disposing the form...
    this.Enabled = false;
    e.Cancel = true;
    var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>myControl.Dispose())
        .ContinueWith(a=>Close(), context);
}
```

Comment: When you mention the form's `FormClosing` event, I assume you mean the form which contains the host which contains the user control, don't you?

Comment: See update; the `.ContinueWith` would be executed on the Form's thread, while the `Dispose` would be executed on a thread pool thread.

Comment: I can't make the control's disposal blocking because it would cause a potential deadlock between `Control.Invoke` and the native object destructor (see original question). I must ensure the native object finished its shutdown process (its thread exited) before I dispose it. I think I will remove the last two lines from your example, and handle an event fired when the native thread ends all the way up to the main form. In that event's handler, I can continue closing the main form. What do you think?

Comment: That would accomplish the same thing.  I wasn't sure of the detail in your circumstance.  My example basically makes the completion of the call to 'myControl.Dispose' an event.  So, you could do the same thing by responding to your control's event and calling 'Form.Close()'.